# problem when deserializing xml with xmlMapper (java)

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I have autogenerated POJOs, to which i want to deserialize XML. XML looks like this:

```
<RootElement>
  <ListOfEntities>
    <Entity>
      <EntityRecord>
        <Field>123</Field>
      </EntityRecord>
    </Entity>
  </ListOfEntities>
<RootElement>
```

autogenerated entities looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "listOfEntitiesType", propOrder = {
    "entity"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
public class ListOfEntitiesType {

    @XmlElement(name = "Entity")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
    protected List<EntityType> entity;
.....
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "entityType", propOrder = {
    "entityRecord"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
public class EntityType {

    @XmlElement(name = "EntityRecord")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
    protected List<EntityRecordType> entityRecord;
.....
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "entityRecordType", propOrder = {
    "field"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
public class EntityRecordType {

    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
    protected String field;
.....
}
```

and root element.

I try to deserialize it with this code:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES).build();
xmlMapper.readValue()
```

And i get error:

```
Unrecognized field "field" (class path.to.autogenerated.classes.EntityType), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "entityRecord"])
```

It looks like when jackson is trying to deserialize ListOfEntities, it iterprets  tag as some kind of wrapper istead of list's element, so it tries to interpret  as element of List. And fails

I tried to code like this:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false).enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES).build();
xmlMapper.readValue()
```

but with no effect.

I have no access neither to use annotations on POJOs (because they are autogenerated) nor to make changes on xsd. Can I somehow tell xmlMapper to deserialize correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are missing `@XmlAttribute` as follows:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "entityRecordType", propOrder = {
    "field"
})
@Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
public class EntityRecordType {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Field")
    @Generated(value = "com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver", date = "2021-09-23T01:56:05+03:00", comments = "JAXB RI v2.3.3")
    protected String field;
.....
}
```

Comment: nope, on lowest class's fields there are only @Generated annotation.

Comment: And this class is autogenerated, so i cant add any annotation

Comment: How are you autogenerating it?